# Patching a python app

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have an old python app running on MS-Windows. The sources are lost :/, but it's still part of our workflow.

I'm trying to patch the code as follows: First, unzip the `library.zip` file, then, run one of the `.pyo` files through [Easy Python Decompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/), then edit the source code, and then recompile it by running `python -O -m py_compile patchedModule.py`. At this point, I re-zip all the files into a new `library.zip` file and try to run. The app doesn't work. I notice the new `library.zip` file is only about half the size of the one that I unzipped. I'm not sure why. Finally, I should say that I'm a complete python noob, and may be making a really obvious mistake. The app was written in python 2.7, and I've got 2.7.10 installed on my machine.

Questions: is there some special way to prepare a `library.zip` file for a python app? And, are there any other steps I need to follow, to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The app doesn't work"  - *what* doesn't work? Do you get a traceback, import error, nothing at all, what do you get?

Comment: I start the exe file and it just crashes. No errors reported.

Comment: How are you running the program?  Try running it from cmd.exe, you might see some diagnostics then.  If you do, post all of it.

Comment: If I run from the cmd line, it exits with the error: `Process 1829587688 is exited with status 255`

Comment: One more observation: if I just un-zip and re-zip the `library.zip` file, without changing anything, the result is only about half the size of the original zip file. If I try launching the app, it crashes immediately as before.

It seems the `library.zip` file is being corrupted, or maybe it's not even a standard zip file?

Any suggestions about how to proceed would be appreciated!